# Azure S2S VPN Gateway connection 0 B data in

Tags: azure, cisco, vnet, azure-vpn

We set up a Azure site to site VPN connection to a Cisco ASA device, which in Azure shows 'connected' and some data out but no data in (0 B). The connection uses IPSec (IKEv2) which seems fine in Azure but shows no traffic on-prem. How is that possible?
Can I eliminate an issue with routing on Azure VNet? (we do have a custom route to direct traffic to VNet Gateway associated with both subnets: default + GatewaySubnet).
Pinging on-prem IP address from Azure VM in the VNet does increase data out, but still nothing is seen on-prem. May it be some NATing issue on-prem?
Any suggestion where to look? TIA.

Comment: Can you disable the firewall of on-prem devivce and then check?

Comment: In the end there was an IP address space overlap with an on-prem network.